# Book recommendation for this course on Statistical Modelling using R

Tags: r, modeling, references

I'm following by myself this [syllabus](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S-eKp5zWRvEArxJc0TM2CyzgMVGd5GeV/view) from the Statistical Modeling course (stat109) from Harvard. The recommended [book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/data-analysis-and-graphics-using-r/E04AEC5BCEF09D2E51A63EB5A8CB0680) (you can have an overview of this book following this link) is from 2010 and it seems it doesn't use the most recent libraries (it uses the plot function instead of the ggplot2 function for graphics in R), even though this course is from spring 2020, very recent.

Do you think I should take another book, a newer one? if so, do you have some recommendations?

Comment: Any book about `ggplot2` has rapidly been outdated, at least in the details.  Use https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ instead.  The process of statistical modeling changes much less rapidly, making it less important to seek out the latest publications; and the concepts and principles change so slowly that much can be learned even from centuries-old material.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: The question is poised uncomfortably between the specific -- what other books match the named syllabus -- and the general -- which other books cover R but are more up-to-date insofar as they are cover currently more popular libraries.

Comment: The book specified, by Maindonald and Braun, is an excellent blend of statistical and programming exposition. Dozens if not hundreds of books on R have been published since but most I have seen have different goals or aren't nearly as good or as sound.  Naturally, exceptions to that impression would be excellent answers.

Comment: @NickCox Very helpful comment, that's exactly what I wanted to know, you understood my point. So I think I will read this book (I'm already in the chapter 3)

Answer (score -1):

The following books on Statistical modeling using R might be helpful

1. **Title :** An Introduction to Statistical Learning: with Applications in R

   **ISBN**: 9781461471370

This book presents some of the most important modeling and prediction techniques, along with relevant applications. Topics include linear regression, classification, resampling methods, support vector machines and clustering.

2. **Title :** Statistics with R: Solving Problems Using Real-World Data

   **ISBN**: 9781506388151

Introduces foundational statistics concepts with beginner-friendly R programming in an exploration of the world’s tricky problems faced by the “R Team” characters. Inspired by the programming group “R Ladies,”

3. **Title :** R Programming - A comprehensive guide

   **ISBN**: 9798654217325

Book covers the R Programming rich graphical and data visualization tools, and
web applications. Statistical concepts such as Descriptive, Inferential, and regression models are also covered. It also includes Machine Learning models such as classification and clustering model

Comment: These books seem to me to be on utterly different levels.  Note that any book that claims to be "A comprehensive guide" usually is nothing of the kind". That is not a problem if any book is what a reader wants but how far do these books match the Harvard syllabus specified in the question?